# Checklistbox adding items

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

[image]

Any know what will be the problem? I want to add Items to checklistbox but nothing happens... Items are CollectionItems in a Table Collection. Tables has a Name property

```
  procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  var

  DisplayName: string;
  c :integer;
  begin



 for C := 0 to Compname.Tables.Count - 1 do
  with cxCheckListBox1.Items.Add do
  begin
  DisplayName := Compname.Tables.Items[C].TableName;
  Tag := C;
end;
```

end;

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DisplayName` is a local variable that is otherwise not used. You should be setting the `Text` property of the new item.

I recommend that you stop using `with`. If you had not done so you would have written code like this:

```
Item := cxCheckListBox1.Items.Add;
Item.DisplayName := ...;
```

The compiler could have rejected that code. As it was, using `with` just cluttered your scope. Please stop using it.

Comment: Sorry but I am very new in Delphi. Can you help a bit more? What is Item? How can I declare it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm assuming that `cxCheckListBox1` is `TcxCheckListBox`. That's not a standard Delphi class. It's a devExpress component. I don't have those components, but I believe that `Items.Add` returns a `TcxCheckListBoxItem`. These components come with documentation which will explain all of this.

Comment: Ok!Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If needed to store in list not only strings but also additional data (for examole some identifier) `Items.Add()` method isn't appropriate. In this case useful is `Items.AddObject()` method.

For example, adding new item:

```
lbFeatures.AddItem(
      qrFeatures.FieldByName('DESCR').AsString,
      TObject(qrFeatures.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger));
```

And read stored ID:

```
if lbFeatures.Checked[I] then
  id := Integer(lbFeatures.Items.Objects[I]);
```